# How to implement react-particles-js with anchor links?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, particles.js

Using [react-particles-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-particles-js)
 as a background on a React project, I discover that disables the anchor tag, don't know if its my implementation

```
 const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App" style={{ position: "relative", overflow: "hidden" }}>
      <div style={{ position: "absolute" }}>
        <Particles height="330vh" width="100vw" params={particlesConfig} />
      </div>
      <Home /> {/*this is the content */}
    </div>
  );
};
```

What it happens its that in this component with link like this

```
        <a
          href="https://tienda-de-garage.herokuapp.com/"
          style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "black" }}
        >
          <p>Tienda de Garage</p>
        </a>
```

Don't work.

I wonder if its the implementation, maybe the use of the view port the increase the size of the area to encompass the background but i'm not sure.

here [its](https://ivan-projects.herokuapp.com/) a live version, with the 1 link not working to show the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `interactivity.detectsOn` to `window` (`InteractivityDetect.window` or `"window"`)

You can see a working sample [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-shadow-qnu4v?file=/src/App.js)

This sample uses `react-tsparticles` but it's the same as `react-particles-js` since they share the same core library `tsparticles`

Comment: I do have, that config :(

Comment: I do remake with your implementation and it works!!! seems its the place of the render, thanks man!!!